# Load third party JS without affecting PageSpeed

Tags: javascript, php, html, wordpress

I have trouble getting good PageSpeed score because of two third party JS which are render blocking resources according to PageSpeed. The two services I use are Intercom and Albacross.

I tried to remove them to see how much improvement it could be done and when I removed it the score when up by almost 30 points on mobile!

The website is build in Wordpress by the way.

Any idea how I can load those JS without affecting PageSpeed? I've tried  and  but it doesn't make a difference in PageSpeed.

I also found this website https://peakon.com which doesn't load Intercom and other third-party JS until **after** you've accepted their cookie policy the first time you visit their page which I think is very clever.

Any idea how they have done it or what I should do?

Thank you!

Comment: You can eliminate render blocking, by loading them in the footer, instead of the header.

Comment: or defer the loading

Answer (score 0):

Well if you want, you could wait until the page has loaded and then load the external sources like so:

```
document.body.onload = function(){
   firstExternalScript = document.createElement("script");
   firstExternalScript.src = "www.linkToIntercom.com";//that would be your script to Intercom or Albacross
   secondExternalScript = document.createElement("script");
   secondExternalScript.src = "www.linkToAlbacross.com";//that would be your script to Intercom or Albacross
   document.body.appendChild(firstExternalScript);
   document.body.appendChild(secondExternalScript);
}
```

Alternatively you could make that into a seperate function and run it when the user accepts the cookie policy like in the example you mentioned:

**HTML**

```
<button class="cookieAcceptBtn" onclick="acceptCookiePolicy();">Accept</button>
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
function acceptCookiePolicy(){
   firstExternalScript = document.createElement("script");
   firstExternalScript.src = "www.linkToIntercom.com";//that would be your script to Intercom or Albacross
   secondExternalScript = document.createElement("script");
   secondExternalScript.src = "www.linkToAlbacross.com";//that would be your script to Intercom or Albacross
   document.body.appendChild(firstExternalScript);
   document.body.appendChild(secondExternalScript);
}
```

I hope this answers your question.